# rails 4 select_tag in form doesn't get saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, crud

I have a select_tag tag in a simple form, like this:

```
<%= f.label :semester, "Please select an option:" %>


<%= select_tag(:semester, options_for_select([['Option One', "Option One"], ['Option two', "Option Two"], ['Option Three', "Option Three"], ['Option Four', "Option Four"]])) %>
```

The controller function that links to this form has nothing non-standard in it and neither does the model for the relevant table. I see the correct parameter is being sent when I look in my heroku logs, but the field corresponding to the select_tag is not actually being updated in the database when people edit a record. All code seems fine to me and I have no idea what I could be mising at the moment. Am I somehow using the select_tag wrong?

Comment: Please post your controller code with permit params method.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<%= f.select(:semester, options_for_select([['Option One', "Option One"], ['Option two', "Option Two"], ['Option Three', "Option Three"], ['Option Four', "Option Four"]])) %>
```

You have forgot to use form object that is why it is not saving.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= f.select(:semester, options_for_select([['Option One', 'Option One'], ['Option two', 'Option Two'], ['Option Three', 'Option Three'], ['Option Four', 'Option Four']]), {include_blank: true}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.select :semester, options_for_select([['Option One', "Option One"], ['Option two', "Option Two"], ['Option Three', "Option Three"], ['Option Four', "Option Four"]]) %>
```